# Drawing drawable using canvas - Clear destination

Tags: android, canvas

I have a custom view. I create a fullscreen transparent overlay using full screen rectangle by calling this method in onDraw:

```
  private void drawOverlay(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getMeasuredHeight(), backgroundPaint);
    }
```

My screen is now overlayed with transparent background I defined earlier.

Now, I want to draw a Drawable on the screen. A drawable can be have a transparent parts on it. It can be, for example a shape , defined like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="@color/transparent"></solid>
    <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="#ffff0716"/>
</shape>
```

Now I want to draw that drawable on the screen. I draw it using this method:

```
 private void drawDrawableOverTargetView(Canvas canvas) {
        Rect rect = new Rect(200, 200, 450, 400); //TODO
        Drawable drawable = tutorial.getHighlightDrawable();
        drawable.setBounds(rect);
        drawable.draw(canvas);
    }
```

The inner part of my oval is defined transparent in xml. When displayed, the inner part of the oval will be the overlay color, because the overlay rectangle is below it. 
The question is: Is it possible to define that drawable should override the color of background rectangle, meaning that the inner part of it becomes transparent ? Is it possible to remove the part of overlay rectangle which is below my drawable?

I tried using

```
drawable.setColorFilter(Color.Transparent, PorterDuff.Mode.Clear);
```

But it doesn't seem to work :/

Answer (score 1):

You're making it way harder than you need to. Canvases maintain what is on them in pixels not objects. When a part of that canvas is invalidated it calls all the draw code relevant there and asks for the new pixels. Just code it up so that it draws the way you'd like it to, and invalidate the area. It'll call up the draw routine again and put them in whatever order you draw them in.

The canvas doesn't recall the background color under objects because there's just pixels not objects. The only sense wherein there are objects is where you draw objections, which causes a rendering of that on the canvas. But you can't remove it. You can however declare the area where that object was drawn to be invalid and upon refresh have it not draw that object the next time draw gets called.

Just make sure you call up the stuff in the order you'd like, as what you'd like changes, have the code draw it in that order.

You can't change the stuff already on the screen after the fact except by one of the blending operations, the Porter-Duff operations simply deal with all the logical ways you can manipulate pixels on a screen. CLEAR for example will restore that area to pure transparent. Which is basically just clearing that section of the screen. There's no circle on the screen. You are writing transparent pixels to a set of pixels that looks like a circle. Don't do that. When you don't want that circle thing, declare the picture invalid and when it calls the draw routine again, do not draw that circle.

After they are drawn, you're modifying pixels not things.